# Problema com Indentação

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recentemente troquei de editor para desenvolvimento.

Com o VS Code tudo se tornou mais fácil e intuitivo, porém frequentemente tenho problema com classes antigas, com relação a indentação.

Quando abro a primeira vez todo o código parece estar bem organizado, porém durante o uso vou vendo que algumas partes não foram indentadas corretamente. Aparece um "espaço estranho", como se fosse 4 espaços em um só, isso faz com que a indentação não funcione perfeitamente, aí preciso sair ajustando manualmente.

Isso é chato por que são centenas de "classes" com milhares de linhas de comando.

Já olhei e a indentação automática do VS Code estivada.

Comment: Sugestão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/460903/3635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que isso ocorre pq o VS Code tem uma configuração de indentação padrão, porém seus arquivos antigos têm outra.

Vc pode usar a opção padrão de formatação do VS code. Aqui tem um vídeo de 15 segundos explicando. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhnlywA-Jrs

Ou vc pode usar alguma extensão tipo Beautify, instale e leia a documentação. Com essa extensão vc consegue facilmente idenentar o arquivo inteiro ou parte dele.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify

Outra opção é mudando configurando o uso do Tab nas configurações do VS Code.
Vá em <kbd>File > Preferences > Settings</kbd> e pesquise por "`Tab`", conforme imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vc também pode dar um `Ctrl+A` para selecionar todas as linhas do arquivo. Depois vai no <kbd>ctrl + shift + p > indent</kbd> conforme na imagem abaixo e escolhe o formato que vc quer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Para definir espaços de indentação, tanto para novos arquivos como para antigos, para 2 neste caso ("editor.tabSize": 2) você deve inserir o seguinte código no arquivo de configuração:

```
"[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features",
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.detectIndentation":false
 }
```

Para acessar a configuração pressione CTRL + SHIT + P e digite na linha de comando:

> Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)

ou para configurar diretamente uma linguagem digite na linha de comando:

> Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings

e escolha a linguagem que deseja configurar

pode-se adicionar configurações específicas para cada liguagem manualmente insira no JSON de configuração settings.json:

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.detectIndentation":false
}
```

**"editor.detectIndentation":false** faz com que identação de arquivos antigos sejam ignorados