# Indentação aleatória para padronizada

Tags: visual-studio-code

Como transformar de forma automática indentação de arquivos com espaçamentos aleatórios como 1, 2 ou 3 espaços para 4 ou qualquer outro valor usado?

A ideia é que fique mais claro para quem está desenvolvendo no momento.

Answer (score 4):

Sugiro que crie um arquivo `.editorconfig` na pasta do projeto com algo como:

```
# EditorConfig is awesome: https://EditorConfig.org

# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

# Estilo unix, usa LF como quebra de linha e adiciona uma linha no vazia no final
[*]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true

# charset utf-8 para py e js
[*.{js,py}]
charset = utf-8

# 4 espaços de indentação para py
[*.py]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4

# Aqui Makefile usará TAB ao invés de espaços
[Makefile]
indent_style = tab

# Se tiver uma pasta chamada lib todos JS usarão 2 espaços para indenção
[lib/**.js]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2

# arquivos como package.json or .travis.yml usarão 2 espaços
[{package.json,.travis.yml}]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

Isso é só um exemplo é claro, depende do tipo de projeto, **mais detalhes de como configurar em https://editorconfig.org/**

Após criado o arquivo instale o plugin no Vscode:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig

No exemplo acima a vantagem disso é para que acaso outras pessoas usem outros editores elas poderão seguir os padrões que você estabelecer